# Derivative work BSD license when not known original work

Tags: licensing, bsd

I want to put a BSD license in some code. I use part of code that doesn't have license information but it belongs to other people who I don't know. It was given to my from other privates but the code it self doesn't have a copyrigth claim. I want to put BSD license to my part of the work. How can I put my BSD license? Is the 2 terms bsd.

Comment: Please edit your question to add some clarification to what exact situation you are in. Where does the code you want to put under BSD license come from? How did you get it? The only answer to your question with the current level of details you gave is: you can't do that.

Comment: Just edited. The thing is that there isn't a copyrigth claim in the original code. I did a lot of editions to the code I only want to put BSD license to my editions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that this is the answer but you can't just put your code under BSD license (or whatever license for that matter, be it open source or proprietary).

The problem here is that you got this code from a third party who wasn't the author and the original author licensed no rights to you on this code.

It is usually considered OK to run the code for private use as long as you got the code lawfully (which could be false if the third party did not get it lawfully, or did not have permission to distribute it). Private modification should also be OK as long as you do not distribute the resulting work.

However, for distributing further a work that is clearly a derivative of an original work, you really need permission from the original copyright owner (even if it's only your modifications that you want to license under BSD-2). Your only solution at that point would be to reach out to the third party you got the code from and ask them who the original copyright owner was, or if they have a license to redistribute it further from them. If you can talk to the copyright owner, then you can ask them permission to release your derivative under BSD-2 license.

Note that the copyright owner is not necessarily an individual, nor the original developer. E.g. if the third party was the employer of the person who developed the code, then it maybe that the third party (or its company) is the copyright owner and you could ask them permission directly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not know the license of the original code. And **no license** means .... **no license**. There is no such thing as an implied license as far as I know. Therefore you cannot relicense something since you are not licensed in the first place.